# Vue.js doesn't update when switched to object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Inside a component I have a elements object:

```js
elements: {
   id: {
      text: '',
      color: '',
      ...
   }
```

That I change by:

```html
<a-textarea
  autoFocus
  placeholder="text to include"
  :style="{ width: '286px', marginTop: '10px' }"
  v-model="elements[currentlyEditingId].text"
/>
```

And display:

```html
<span
 v-for="(element, id) in elements"
 :key="id"
>
  <span
    v-if="element.type === 1"
    :style="{
      position:'absolute',
      display: 'block',
      width: '90%',
      padding: '0'

      color: colors[element.color],
      textAlign:  element.align,
      fontSize: `${element.size}px`,
      marginTop: `${element.margin}vh`,
      fontWeight: element.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal',
      fontStyle: element.italic ? 'italic' : 'normal',
      textDecoration: element.underline ? 'underline' : 'none',
    }"
  >
    {{ element.text }}
  </span>
</span>
```

Before an update I had the elements object as an array and everything worked fine (I had to change because objects are simpler to manage)

I noticed that  when I changed the array to be an object when I edit the object (2nd paragraph), the DOM doesn't update.

I tried to add `this.$forceUpdate` but there are too many places where it does't update and the code would result messy.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Vue only observes the 1st level of properties/keys inside your object - but you are updating the 2nd level (nested) properties. My advice is to keep using an Array but also add a computed property which will convert the array into a map so you can directly access your objects by id - but still have their keys on the 1st level.

Comment: How can I implement that computed?

Comment: Do you have a codesanbox for your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue only observes the 1st level of properties/keys inside your object - but you are updating the 2nd level (nested) properties. My advice is to keep using an Array but also add a computed property which will convert the array into a map so you can directly access your objects by id - but still have their keys on the 1st level.

```js
elements: [
   {
      id: 1,
      text: '',
      color: '',
      ...
   },
   ...
  ]

computed:
{
  mapElements()
  {
    const result = {}
    this.elements.forEach(item =>
    {
      result[item.id] = item
    })
    return result
  }
}
```

Then you can update like this

```html
<a-textarea
  autoFocus
  placeholder="text to include"
  :style="{ width: '286px', marginTop: '10px' }"
  v-model="mapElements[currentlyEditingId].text"
/>
```

And display

```html
<span
 v-for="element in elements"
 :key="element.id"
>
  <span
    v-if="element.type === 1"
    :style="{
      position:'absolute',
      display: 'block',
      width: '90%',
      padding: '0'

      color: colors[element.color],
      textAlign:  element.align,
      fontSize: `${element.size}px`,
      marginTop: `${element.margin}vh`,
      fontWeight: element.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal',
      fontStyle: element.italic ? 'italic' : 'normal',
      textDecoration: element.underline ? 'underline' : 'none',
    }"
  >
    {{ element.text }}
  </span>
</span>
```